# CloudKitJS Server to Server Configure

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I keep getting the following error:

```
[Error: No key provided to sign]
```

Here is my config code:

```
CloudKit.configure({
  services: {
    fetch: fetch
  },
  containers: [{
    containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.io.shakd.Command-Center',
    environment: 'development',
    serverToServerKeyAuth: {
        keyID: "MyKeyId",
        privateKeyFile: "./eckey.pem",
        privateKeyPassPhrase: "MyPassPhrase"
    }

  }]
})
```

Also, what is the privateKeyPassPhrase? Is it the code that was generated in the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Apple's sample code at [CloudKit Catalog: An Introduction to CloudKit (Cocoa and JavaScript)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014599), shows that the required syntax for `privateKeyFile` is to prepend `__dirname` (the directory of the executing Node script) to the `eckey.pem` file. From `config.js`:

```
serverToServerKeyAuth: {
    keyID: '<insert key ID>',
    privateKeyFile: __dirname + '/eckey.pem'
}
```

The second critical piece of information is that after configuring CloudKit, you have to explicitly sign in using `setUpAuth()`. From `index.js`:

```
var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
var database = container.publicCloudDatabase; // We'll only make calls to the public database.

// Sign in using the keyID and public key file.
container.setUpAuth().then(function (userInfo) {
    println("userInfo", userInfo);
    return database.performQuery({ recordType: 'Test' });
}).then(function (response) {
    println("Queried Records", response.records);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.warn(error);
});
```

After making these two changes in my JavaScript code, my script was authenticated for reading and writing to my CloudKit database.

Comment: All I needed to do is call container.setUpAuth();

Answer (score 1):

You only need privateKeyPassPhrase if your privateKeyFile is encrypted with a pass phrase.

The error

```
[Error: No key provided to sign]
```

comes straight from node's crypto module.

Looks like your eckey.pem file doesn't contain a private key.
You can try the following to verify:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./eckey.pem', 'utf8');
var signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
signer.update('message');
console.log(signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64'));
```

If that works, then your configuration should be:

```
CloudKit.configure({
  services: {
    fetch: fetch
  },
  containers: [{
    containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.io.shakd.Command-Center',
    environment: 'development',
    serverToServerKeyAuth: {
        //that looks suspicious, please use the real keyID
        keyID: "MyKeyId",
        privateKeyFile: "./eckey.pem"
    }
  }]
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "if that works"? Thanks. I got some encrypted output, but still get the error no key provided to sign.